# OData Client doesn't include error message when Bad Request Response received from OData Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, odata

I have an odata client (generated using odata connected service) to call a odata service and add some data.

```cs
public async Task<ActionResult> AddOrder(Order order)
{
    try
    {
        var client = new Container(new Uri(ConfigHelper.ApiUrl)) { Timeout = 60 * 60,  
            AddAndUpdateResponsePreference = DataServiceResponsePreference.IncludeContent
            };
        client.AddToOrder(order);
        client.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Json("Error: AddOrder request failed. " + ex.Message + " : " + ex.InnerException?.Message);
    }
    return Json("AddOrder request has completed successfully");
}
```

Odata service implementation

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(Order order)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
    try
    {
        db.Order.Add(order);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync()
        return Created(order);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

the OData service returns BadRequest response incase of model validation errors. for example, below is one sample response from the service

```
Status Code:400

Header Info:-
Pragma:no-cache
OData-Version:4.0
Content-Length:221
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Type:application/json; odata.metadata=minimal; charset=utf-8
Date:Sun, 27 Nov 2022 07:06:49 GMT
Expires:-1
Server:Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
{"error":{"code":"","message":"The request is invalid.","innererror":{"message":"order.ProductName : The field ProductName must be a string or array type with a maximum length of '20'.\r\n","type":"","stacktrace":""}}}
```

the client.SaveChanges() call throws an exception in this case but the exception does not include the innnererror message indicating the validation error message. all it says **BadRequest**

InnerException:

[image]

Response property of exception:

[image]

I've tried updating the OData Client nuget package, tried setting option `SaveChangesOptions.BatchWithIndependentOperations` when calling `SaveChanges()`, no luck. could some please help?

```
client.SaveChanges(SaveChangesOptions.BatchWithIndependentOperations);
```

currently using Microsoft.OData.Client version 7.12.5 which is the latest version.

Answer (score 2):

I presume that you received `DataServiceRequestException`.

`DataServiceRequestException` has a property `Response` of `DataServiceResponse type`.

`DataServiceResponse` is a collection of `OperationResponse` and each `OperationResponse` has a property `Error` with an error thrown by the operation.

Here you should be able to find more details what exactly failed.

[DataServiceRequestException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.odata.client.dataservicerequestexception?view=odata-client-7.0)

[DataServiceResponse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.odata.client.dataserviceresponse?view=odata-client-7.0)

[OperationResponse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.odata.client.operationresponse?view=odata-client-7.0)

Comment: thanks a lot <3.  correct, received DataServiceRequestException and i have inspected the OperationResponse, but it also missing the validation error message received in the response body. i've update the question with the screenshot.